# What values does torch.Conv2D return?

Tags: pytorch

```
x = torch.randn(3,64,161,161)\
model = nn.Conv2d(64, 1, kernel_size=1) result = model(x)\
print(result.shape)
```

> output : 3, 1, 161, 161

Output has the first two values as 3 and 1. I understood it as :
3 means the number of input channels that the model has initially received.
1 means the number of output channels after the model dealt with the tensor.

Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the number of input channels is 64 (the number of output channels is 1). 3 is the batch size in your code snippet.

The convention PyTorch uses for all tensors with 2D multi-channel data is to have shape `[N,C,H,W]` where

- `N` is batch dimension
- `C` is channel dimension
- `H` is height dimension
- `W` is width dimension

For `Conv2d`

`N` will be the same for both the input and output tensors since each batch element in the input tensor produces one corresponding element in the output tensor.

The input tensor's `C` must be equal to `in_channels`. This is the first argument you provided to `Conv2d`. In your case it is `64` so you need to have an input tensor with `64` channels.

The output tensor's `C` will be equal to `out_channels`. This is the second argument you provide to `Conv2d`. In your case it is `1` so the output tensor will have `1` channel.

`W` and `H` are the width and height of the data that is being convolved. The output shape will vary depending on the `kernel_size`, `padding`, `stride`, and `dilation` arguments of `Conv2d`. The equation relating input `W` and `H` to output `W` and `H` is

[image]

For more information I recommend you check the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#torch.nn.Conv2d).